Interpreting Lagged Dependent Variable in Binary Logistic Regression
I am running a binary logistic regression to test the purchasing of a gym membership in 2021 against a series of controls (ie. income, gender). Included amongst these control is a lagged dependent variable - namely, whether a gym membership was purchased in 2020.
The odds-ratio result for the lagged DV is 23.2. Am I correct in interpreting this as basically saying, holding all other factors constant (ie. income, gender), those who purchased a gym membership in 2020 were 23.2x more likely to do so in 2021, compared to those who did not in 2020.

Have you read any of our posts concerned with interpreting odds ratios?

Thank you for the direction. I have had a look and understand odds-ratios I just wanted to check that this still applies with a lagged DV.

Why would it not apply?  Do you have some specific cause of your doubt?

I was pretty sure it would I just didn't know if lagged DVs could only be used for certain kinds of regression - been trying to teach myself it for the past few days so just wanted some reassurance!
